# Write a retry mechanism in Python using functions as arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming

I'd like to write a retry mechanism in Python for unstable network communication.

My service has multiple types of methods:

```
method1()
method2(arg1)
method3(arg1, arg2)
```

I'd like to pass the method to a function which will retry whatever method is passed to it (I think it might look like this):

```
retry (service.method1)
retry (service.method2, arg1)
retry (service.method3, arg1, arg2)
```

How do I write this retry method?  Unfortunately I am using Python 2.7.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def retry(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way the first argument to `retry` is the function (method), and it will take an arbitrary number of arguments and keyword arguments and pass them on to `fn`. This is often called "unpacking", though in other languages I've heard it called "splat".

This version just calls it immediately, but you could add a delay, or a loop or something as needed.

---

> I'd like to know more about the syntax that you used here. What am I looking at?

```
>>> def print_them(*args, **kwargs):
...     print(args, kwargs)  # args is a tuple & kwargs is a dict
...   
>>> print_them(1, 2, 3, spam='foo', bacon='bar')
(1, 2, 3) {'spam': 'foo', 'bacon': 'bar'}
>>> print(1, 2, 3, sep=':')       
1:2:3
>>> print(*[1, 2, 3], **{'sep': ':'})  # equivalent to the above
1:2:3
```

It's part of the syntax for function definitions and function calls, just like the  `,` or `()` is. It has a completely different meaning than the exponent and multiplication operators.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the syntax that  you used here. What am I looking at? single *, double *...
https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/